# Python-mode's linters not working on 4 vim installations

Tags: python, vim, lint, python-mode

Too All,

I cannot get python-mode's linters to work on 4 vim installations.

On 2 PC's running Windows 10, and Python 2.7.14, I upgraded from vim 7.4 to 8.1.   Steps as follows for vim 8.1:

```
mkdir C:\Users\Steve\vimfiles\pack\plugins\opt
cd C:\Users\Steve\vimfiles\pack\plugins\opt
git clone https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode
cd pymode
git submodule update --init --recursive
:packadd python-mode
:helptags ~/vimfiles/pack/plugins/opt/python-mode
```

my _vimrc and .vimrc (see Ubuntu installations below) for several years have this:

```
" pymode - Note:  see :help Pymode for defaults already set
let g:pymode_trim_whitespaces = 1          " trim unused white spaces on save
let g:pymode_indent = 1                       " PEP8-compatible python indent
let g:pymode_doc = 1                      " turns on the documentation script
let g:pymode_lint_on_write = 1 " check code on save if file has been modified
let g:pymode_quickfix_maxheight = 12
let g:pymode_lint_signs = 0             " don't show left error symbol column
let g:pymode_lint_checkers = ['pylint', 'pyflakes', 'pep8', 'mccabe']
```

In Windows 10, when I test the linters with deliberate coding errors, nothing happens.

On the 2 PC's running Windows 10, I have the Ubuntu subsystem installed which includes Python 2.7.12, Python 3.5.2, and vim 7.4.  I use Vundle to manage my plugins.  Steps as follows for vim 7.4 with Vundle:

```
:PluginClean   (to remove old python-mode)
:PluginInstall    (to install new python-mode)
:q
cd .vim/bundle/python-mode
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

In Ubuntu, when I test the linters with deliberate coding errors, the 1st error is reported and then the linters quit.

I have used python-mode's linters for several years on several different computers.  Either something is broken in this version of python-mode, or I did something wrong in 4 python-mode installations.  Please help.

Thank you,

Steve

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Romainl,Can you please provide clarification on how I can use the plugin's issue tracker.  Once I have that information, I will do this. Thanks, Steve

Comment: @SteveHaymes I guess what romainl meant was posting this as an issue on the error reporting site of the plugin you are using as this sounds like it isn't working properly. Unfortunately I can't point you to one as I am unfamiliar with the plugin.

Comment: You go to the plugin's issue tracker and you use it. Simple.

Comment: Modus Tollens, Thanks for the directions, done:  https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/902

Comment: With some additional testing, on 2 computers running Windows 10, when I move the python-mode directory from:

C:\Users\Steve\vimfiles\pack\plugins\opt

to

C:\Users\Steve\vimfiles\pack\plugins\start

the linters work correctly in vim 8.1.

So, by using the new default for plugins in vim 8.n (which I like BTW, instead of using Vundle as I did in earlier versions of vim), python-mode does not work when it is in opt, after I type

:packadd python-mode.

I would like to know the underlying cause of this problem though.  Is this a vim 8.n problem, python-mode problem, or both?